# React Native rerendering UI after using array.map

Tags: reactjs, react-native, user-interface, render

I am attempting to have an icon switch its visual when clicked (like a checkbox). Normally in react native I would do something like this:

```
const [checkbox, setCheckbox] = React.useState(false);
...
<TouchableHighlight underlayColor="transparent" onPress={() => {setCheckbox(!setCheckbox)}}> 
    {added ? <MaterialIcons  name="playlist-add-check" size={40} />
    : <MaterialIcons  name="playlist-add" size={40} />}
</TouchableHighlight>
```

However I have made some changes, and now I can't seem to replicate this behavior. I am using AsyncStorage class to storage and get arrays of objects for display. For simplification, in the example below I removed the storage code, and the objects each have an 'id' and an 'added' attribute, which is essentially the boolean value of the checkbox.

I am now attempting to update the icon shown to the user whenever it is pressed. I know the function is being called, but it will not update the icon. I am using array.map to create the list of icons. I created a demo here, and the code is below: https://snack.expo.dev/@figbar/array-map-icon-update

```
const templateObject = {
  id: 0,
  added: false,
};
const templateObject2 = {
  id: 1,
  added: true,
};
export default function App() {
  const [savedNumbers, setSavedNumbers] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setSavedNumbers([templateObject,templateObject2]);
  }, []);

  const populateSavedNumbers = () =>
    savedNumbers.map((num, index) => <View key={index}>{renderPanel(num.id,num.added)}</View>);
  const updateNumber = (id) => {
    let capturedIndex = -1;
    for(var i = 0; i < savedNumbers.length; i += 1) {
        if(savedNumbers[i].id === id) {
          capturedIndex = i;
          break;
        }
    }
    let _tempArray = savedNumbers;
    _tempArray[capturedIndex].added = !_tempArray[capturedIndex].added;
    setSavedNumbers(_tempArray);
  }
  const renderPanel = (id:number, added:boolean) => {
    return (
        <View>
          <TouchableHighlight underlayColor="transparent" onPress={() => {updateNumber(id);}}> 
              {added ? <MaterialIcons  name="playlist-add-check" size={40} />
              : <MaterialIcons  name="playlist-add" size={40} />}
           </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>
    );
  }
  return (
    <View>
    <View>buttons:</View>
      <View>{populateSavedNumbers()}</View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common React pitfall where things don't re-render when it seems like they should. React does shallow comparisons between new and old states to decide whether or not to trigger a re-render. This means that, when declaring a variable to simply equal a state variable which is an object or an array, a re-render is not triggered since those two variables now reference the same underlying data structure.

In this case, you are setting `_tempArray` to reference the array `savedNumbers` rather than creating a new array. Therefore, React's shallow comparison comes back as "equal", and it doesn't believe that a re-render is necessary.

To fix this, change this line:

```
let _tempArray = savedNumbers;
```

to this:

```
let _tempArray = [...savedNumbers];
```